# imputing censored data when marginal sums are known

Tags: r, data-imputation, censoring

Let's say I have a large dataset of counts of all the fruits stored in the U.S. by State for a certain snapshot in time.

```
Fruit      Alabama Alaska Arizona . . . . US total
Apples     #       #      #               #
Cherries   #       #      #               #
Grapes     #       #      #               #
Oranges    #       #      #               #
Pears      #       #      #               #
.
.
All fruits #       #      #               #
```

Unfortunately, these counts are sometimes censored, often (but not always) because they were too small. Furthermore, the censorship does not allow me to distinguish between censored nonzero counts and censored counts which are actually zero.

However, the data provide the actual marginal totals as shown above (i.e. total count of each fruit in the U.S., and total number of all fruits for each state), and fortunately there is no censorship in these marginal totals. These sums *include* counts from the cells which are obscured by censorship.

In the same dataset, I also have counts of each category of fruit by state:

```
Category  Alabama Alaska Arizona . . . . US total
Berry     #       #      #               #
Citrus    #       #      #               #
Drupe     #       #      #               #
Pome      #       #      #               #
.
.
All types #       #      #               #
```

These categories are exhaustive (all fruits are perfectly nested in the categories), and there is *no* censorship in these data. These category sums include counts of fruits whose values are censored in the first table.

I'm looking for a solution in R that will impute the missing values based on the constraints provided by the known marginal and categorical sums. However, to add a wrinkle to the problem, the summing is not exact. All counts in all cells are rounded to the nearest 10, and this will create some random error in the summing (as the marginal sums were calculated by summing the actual non-rounded counts, then rounding afterward to nearest 10). But this error is overall very small.

This looks to me like solving essentially a massive system of equations. I don't know ahead of time how deterministic the system will be (probably only partially deterministic). Also, I'd like the solution if possible to make use of the known national ratios of fruits when imputing missing values. So for example if the algorithm has to distribute 40 missing fruits in a particular state between apples and oranges, I'd like it to do so by using the known ratio of total apples to oranges in the nation. So if there are 3x as many apples as oranges in the nation, I'd like the algorithm to assign 30 of the missing fruits in that state to apples and 10 to oranges. If possible.

Thanks for any advice on this and especially how to implement it in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem that can be represented by a matrix -- with row and column sums corresponding to the values you have. If you can get a guess of your original matrix (say, by using expected state-shares across fruits), you could use a simulated annealing algorithm. Something like:

`# with a matrix "replaced" and vector "replacer":`

```
t <- 1
samp.vec <- # some vector to fill the elements of the 
mperc <- .1
while(mperc > .0001){ 
  t <- t+1
  samp.vec <- (samp.vec)[keep] # you could iteratively drop as you get close...
  swap <- sample(samp.vec, 2)  # randomly swap to cells of samp.vec

  original <- replacer  # save it

  # modify your sampling vector
  if(sample(1:2, 1) == 1) {  # randomly either wiggle the replacer
    replacer[swap] <- replacer[swap]  + round(c(100, -100) / log(t) *2)
  } else {  # or cut the number in both cells
    replacer[swap] <- replacer[swap]  + round(c(-100, -100) / log(t) *2)
  }

  # calculate errors before ...
  err1 <- mean(abs(  # difference  ))
    # HERE are some other potential error functions:
    # mean(sqrt((  # difference  )^2)) 

  # ... and after replacement
  replacer[swap][replacer[swap] < 0] <- 0
  replaced[indices] <- replacer
  err2 <- mean(abs(  # difference  ))

  if(err2 >= err1)
    replacer <- original   # undo
    replaced[indices] <- original
  } else {
    # any kind of progress reporting you want...
    }
}
```